# Possible Bug? Got a whole bunch of "Yearling" notices at once

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, yearling-badge

[image]

My awards today showed at least 6 "Yearling" awards, all to the same Law.SE site.

I could understand if I got different Yearlings on different SE sites (although I've joined different SE sites at differing times throughout the year).

Is this a bug?